# How to select text in Iterm using hotkeys

Tags: zsh, iterm, oh-my-zsh

I am using iTerm as terminal and zsh with oh-my-zsh as shell. Sometimes I would like to select part of entered command only using hot keys.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you want to do after selecting? Edit, remove, copy? If you want to copy some text, would it be only for use within the active shell session or for pasting into another program?

Comment: @Adaephon yes, I would like copy/past some for text selection

Answer (score 0):

You can set up vi-keybindings and use vi commands for editing text.

```
binkey -v
```

This command enables vi-keybindings. If you're not a vi user this might not be a (good, useful) solution for you, but anyway:

<kbd><esc></kbd> - go to normal mode
      now navigate to begining/end of the text you want to select
    <kbd>v</kbd> - go to visual mode
      navigate to the other end of the text you want to select
    <kbd>d</kbd> - cut it
    <kbd>i</kbd> - go back to insert mode

If you want to paste it back:

<kbd><esc></kbd> - go to normal mode
<kbd>p</kbd> - paste the previously cut text
<kbd>i</kbd> - go back to insert mode

Note that <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> *copy and paste neither from the primary selection nor from the clipboard*.

If you want to paste from the primary selection (i.e. the text currently selected in X) you can use the global shortcut <kbd>shift + insert</kbd>